# Scroll to top fails on page loaded into ID of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page has an ID (#C2) where other html pages load (giving the effect of a single page).  The load is done with this javascript:

```
function ShowAjax(type) {
    var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
```

On one of the pages that loads into the ID of the main page I need a "scroll to top."  For that, I use a div with an on-click handler that calls a javascript jquery function (ScrollTop).  Here's the link:

```
<div class="C1"><button class="button_01" id="first" onclick="ScrollTop();">Scroll to Top</button></div>
```

Here's the javascript / jquery:

```
<script>
function ScrollTop(){
$("a[href='#bkmkAA']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;}
});</script>
```

My problem is that on click, it does nothing, and the Firefox dev console says:
"ReferenceError: ScrollTop is not defined."  I have js all over my pages, and this javascript is definitely defined on the page.

My question is whether this is related to the page load into an ID of the main page (unlikely) or something else.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

UPDATE:

@Robin Zigmond - here's how the last of the paragraphs looks on the page:

```
<div class="h1_info" id="bkmk24"><b>Section Header 24</b></div><br><div class="set_01">Sentence 1.&nbsp;&nbsp;Sentence 2.&nbsp;&nbsp;Sentence 3.&nbsp;&nbsp;Sentence 4.<div class="C1"><button class="button_01" id="first" onclick="ScrollTop()";">Scroll to Top()_NEW</button></div></div><br>

<script>
function ScrollTop(){
$("a[href='#bkmkAA']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;}
});</script>
```

From this it looks like the script is in scope, as it follows immediately below the end of the last paragraph.  What am I missing?

Comment: well the problem is clearly that `ScrollTop` isn't in scope when the function is called - even though you clearly think it is. Perhaps it's only defined in one of the dynamically-loaded HTML documents, and not in the one you currently have. But there's no way to do more than guess the explanation without further code. [Also, although this isn't relevant to this problem, you'll need the `onclick` to call the function -  `ScrollTop()`, not just an inert function reference.]

Comment: @Robin Zigmond - I just posted an update above showing the last paragraph and the script that follows it immediately.  If that's not enough to know then I'll post more.  Thanks.

Comment: It should be: onclick="ScrollTop()" not onclick="ScrollTop;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the function correctly. Change your HTML code to the following:

```
<div class="C1"><button class="button_01" id="first" onclick="ScrollTop()">Scroll to Top</button></div>
```

Moreover, you do not need to bind an event inside `scrollTop()` function. Replace it with the following and you're done:

```
function ScrollTop(){
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    return false;
}
```

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
function ScrollTop() {
    document.querySelector('html, body').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start'
    });
}
```

If you want to scroll to a page section, check out [this blog post](https://attacomsian.com/blog/smooth-scroll-page-section-jquery).

Comment: @attacomisian - that works, except that instead of scrolling to the top of the page it scrolls up one line and stops.  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer and added `stop()` before `animate()`. It will stop all currently-running animations.